# perfect forwarding dilemma

Tags: c++, c++11

say I have this struct:

```
template <typename ...A>
struct A
{
  void f(A&& ...args)
  {
    fwd(std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename ...B>
  void g(B&& ...args)
  {
    fwd(std::forward<B>(args)...);
  }
};
```

Will `f` and `g` both forward perfectly, if `A... == B...`? IMO, they should, but I am just asking to be sure.

EDIT:
The reason for this question is the common lecture about how perfectly forwarding functions should always be template functions. Obviously this is not true for `f`.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *will they both forward perfectly*. `f()` only accepts rvalue references as arguments, and will forward them along as rvalues to `fwd()`. `g()` accepts both lvalue and rvalue references, and will forward them along while maintaining the respective value categories.

Comment: @Praetorian: Why only rvalue-references? We don't know what instantiation of `A` was used. Like, `A<int>` `A<int&>` `Aint const&>` `A<int&&>`...

Comment: What you say happens because of deduction rules, what if you instantiate explicitly? That is, you can instantiate `A` with reference type parameter(s).

Comment: @Deduplicator Good point, didn't think of those cases. Even so, the lvalueness or rvalueness of `f()`'s arguments is fixed, which is not the case for `g()`.

Comment: @Praetorian It might be if `A... == B...`, as I wrote in my question.

Comment: In that case, both functions should behave identically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will `f` and `g` both forward perfectly, if `A... == B...`?

Yes. I see no reason whatsoever for which they shouldn't.

Comment: As you can see in the comments above, sometimes there is some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `A... == B...`, there is no difference in behaviour. However, the reason for the common advice about forwarding functions needing to be templated is that you would rather have the compiler deduce the types(as in the case of a function template) instead of you having to specify the correct types(as in the case of a class template). This difference is illustrated by the following snippet for a type `X`(of course, they don't satisfy `A... == B...`) :

```
X x;
A<X>::f(X());
A<X>::g(X());//here, f and g have the same behaviour

A<X>::f(x);//fails to compile, since A<X>::f expects an rvalue ref.
A<X>::g(x);//works as expected - Here, B... = X&, while A... = X.

A<const X&>::f(X());//oh noes! fwd gets a const X&.
A<const X&>::g(X());//forwards correctly as B... = X, even though A... = const X&.
```